# Sending email to all users

Tags: wp-cron, wp-mail

What is the best practice to send an email to a large number of users?

I am developing a plugin for the website of an association and one of the things needed is to be able to send an email to all (or a specific subset) of the members of the association.

This will be a fairly rare thing to happen, but when it happens 500 to 1000 emails are expected to be sent.

Now, I can think of several options:

1. Send each email separately
2. Send email in blocks of 50/100
3. Send one single email for everyone

Option 1 is nice because I can personalize the email (Dear Name Surname, ....), however we can live with a generic email for these situations.

- What are the drawbacks of each of those options?
- Can you advise any alternative strategy? I was going to simply use `wp_mail` but maybe relying on an external service (which one?) is better? I would like to avoid setting up a mailing list on an external server, I don't want to have two different databases with user info
- Is there a way to send the emails at regular intervals maybe using `wp_cron`? How would you go about it?

Any further advice is very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending mass emails *that actually get delivered* is not a simple matter at all. Even if your code sends 1000 messages correctly, many if not most of them will get blocked or labeled as spam unless you comply with a long list of mass email [best practices](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Amazon_SES_Best_Practices.pdf). (See also: The FTC's [CAN-SPAM Act - Compliance Guide](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business).)

I recommend that you use (or study the code of) a well-established [newsletter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=newsletter) with a high rating, as these are more likely to employ best practices for deliverability. You might also install a plugin to send outgoing emails via [Mandrill](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/) or [AmazonSES](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ses/). (With [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), you can send up to 12,000 emails a month for free.) These services have established relationships with ISPs and spam blacklisting services, so they can better assure the deliverability of your mass emails.

Comment: This answer does not specify which of the three options mentioned by [nico](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/70169/nico) above is best, though. I set up an [Eleastic Email](https://elasticemail.com/) account and installed [their plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elastic-email-sender/), which hooks to `wp_mail`. But I'm not sure if it is better to have a big loop with an individual call to `wp_mail` for each user (options 1 or 3), or a single call to `wp_mail` targeting all users, or something in between (option 2). Any idea?